# How do I pull images from a Javascript array and place them into HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, json

I have the following array of code containing images and their meta Data.
`

```
const images = [
    {
        "src": "Image1.jpeg",
        "title": "A two tone wall",
        "tags": ["wall", "two tone"]

    },
    {
    "src": "image2.jpeg", 
    "title": "Cute doggy", 
    "tags": ["dog", "walkies"]
},
{
    "src": "image3.jpeg",
    "title": "Natural splendor", 
    "tags": ["natural", "mountain"]
},
{
    "src": "image4.jpeg",
    "title": "Man looking at phone", 
    "tags": ["man", "phone"]
},
{
    "src": "image5.jpeg",
    "title": "Wavey wave",
    "tags": ["water", "wave"]
},
{
    "src": "image6.jpeg",
    "title": "Mountain range",
        "tags": ["mountain", "grass"]
    }

]`
```

and want to place them into a 2 x 3 Grid with attached meta data. At the moment I have tried parsing them using JQUERY into 2 different rows as objects but only text is showing.

Can anyone help me? I'm pretty new to Javascript but understand the principles.

Comment: Please show the code used to display the text. Take a few minutes to read through [ask] and [mcve]. Stackoverflow isn't a free coding service. The objective is to help you improve your current code, not create it from scratch for you

Comment: You forgot to post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```js
const cont = document.querySelector(".cont");

const images = [
    {
        "src": "https://picsum.photos/300/200",
        "title": "A two tone wall",
        "tags": ["wall", "two tone"]

    },
    {
    "src": "https://picsum.photos/320/200", 
    "title": "Cute doggy", 
    "tags": ["dog", "walkies"]
},
{
    "src": "https://picsum.photos/330/200",
    "title": "Natural splendor", 
    "tags": ["natural", "mountain"]
},
{
    "src": "https://picsum.photos/300/210",
    "title": "Man looking at phone", 
    "tags": ["man", "phone"]
},
{
    "src": "https://picsum.photos/300/220",
    "title": "Wavey wave",
    "tags": ["water", "wave"]
},
{
    "src": "https://picsum.photos/300/230",
    "title": "Mountain range",
     "tags": ["mountain", "grass"]
    }

];

images.forEach(function(par){
  cont.innerHTML += `<img src="${par.src}" alt="${par.title}">`;
});
```

```css
.cont {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont"></div>
```